# return keys from array having same values in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

How to find out elements of array having same value_entries. As code is in ruby, looking better approach.

**Input**

```
"block_device": {
  "sda": {
    "size": "83886080",
    "removable": "0",
    "model": "VBOX HARDDISK",
    "rev": "1.0",
    "state": "running",
    "timeout": "30",
    "vendor": "ATA",
    "rotational": "1"
  },
  "sdb": {
    "size": "16384",
    "removable": "0",
    "model": "VBOX HARDDISK",
    "rev": "1.0",
    "state": "running",
    "timeout": "30",
    "vendor": "ATA",
    "rotational": "1"
  },
  "sdc": {
    "size": "16384",
    "removable": "0",
    "model": "VBOX HARDDISK",
    "rev": "1.0",
    "state": "running",
    "timeout": "30",
    "vendor": "ATA",
    "rotational": "1"
  }
}
```

**Sample Code Block:**

```
devicesForRaid = []
deviceHolder = []
node['block_device'].each do |deviceName,deviceProperty|
   deviceHolder.push(deviceName,deviceProperty['size'])       #['sda'=>'83886080','sdb'=>'16384','sdc'=>'16384']
end

deviceHolder.each do | deviceName,deviceSize|

    # how to get deviceName who all having same size

    if(deviceSize_match_found){
        devicesForRaid.push(deviceName)
    }
end
```

**Expected Output:**

```
devicesForRaid = ['sdb','sdc']
```

**Trial way:**

using stack, 
push 1st element onto stack, and comparing with rest of array element.

if match found, push that element onto stack.

**Sample code block completion or better code highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
node['block_device'].each{|k, v| res[v[:size]]<<k}
```

gives:

```
=> {"83886080"=>[:sda], "16384"=>[:sdb, :sdc]}
```

I guess you want to look through `res` for values with length of 2 or more

```
res.to_a.select{|k, v| v.size > 1}
```

Comment: I think, `{"83886080"=>[:sda], "16384"=>[:sdb, :sdc]}.to_a.select{|k, v| v.size > 1}` will give the output: `[["16384", [:sdb, :sdc]]]` which is slightly off from the expected output. You may want to do something like this: `{"83886080"=>[:sda], "16384"=>[:sdb, :sdc]}.select{|k, v| v.size > 1}.values.flatten`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
input_hash[:block_device].each_with_object({}) { |(k,g),h|
  h.update(g[:size]=>[k]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"83886080"=>[:sda], "16384"=>[:sdb, :sdc]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs the block:

```
{ |_,o,n| o+n }
```

to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

Comment: Isn't `o+n` going to create a new array each time? Can you use `o<<n.first` instead?

Comment: @John, yes, though each will be marked for garbage collection as soon as it's replaced by the next one.

Comment: Of course, but it makes the worst case complexity quadratic. Probably not significant when enumerating volumes though

Comment: @John, hmmm. The block that I'm using here is so common that I wonder if (as an optimization) `update` might use `concat` rather than `+` when it sees it.

Comment: If we're talking array allocation, `each_with_object` already allocates one for each enumerated key, value pair. To be super optimized, it could use `each_pair` and a pre-instantiated object instead.

Comment: @Drenmi, That's still just extra O(n) complexity. The quadratic is potentially more serious - especially if it is widely used.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, It's definitely quadratic in 2.2.1 according to a quick test I just did comparing `{ |_,o,n| o+n } ` to `{ |_,o,n| o<<n.first}`. So something to keep in mind when using this pattern with mutables

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (assuming `block_device` is a key in your input data hash):

```
hash = input_data[:block_device]
new_hash = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }
hash.each do |k, v|
  new_hash[v[:size]] << k
end
p new_hash
# => {"83886080"=>[:sda], "16384"=>[:sdb, :sdc]}
```

From this `new_hash`, you can extract your required data easily.

e.g. if you want to extract the elements that has a size more than 1, you can do this:

```
p new_hash.select { |k,v| v.length > 1 }.values.flatten
# => [:sdb, :sdc]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `group_by`?

```
node[:block_device]
  .group_by {|device, attributes| attributes[:size] }
  .map {|size, devices| devices.size > 1 ? devices.map(&:first) : nil }
  .compact
  .flatten
=> [:sdb, :sdc]
```

I think this way is easy to understand what you are doing.